# What is the sentence that is said before the real statement, to let the other person know what is coming, called?

Tags: terminology, speech

Example: **Don't be angry at me for asking this question**, but are you rich?

Is there a term for the sentence in bold?

Comment: As it contains material not directly connected with the content of the matrix sentence, it is an example of a pragmatic marker. This one is in what one could call the 'pre-emptive' class; it's a type of _hedge_.

Comment: 'Disclaimer' comes to mind.

Comment: In this context, the words in bold are actually a **clause**, not a sentence.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

*Preamble* is accurate; however, I believe in casual conversation that **preface** would be more usual.

> **preface** *noun* 2 : the introductory remarks of a speaker or author ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preface))

It is often used in its [verb form](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preface#Verb) for just this sort of *hedge* (also a good option):

> Let me **preface** this by saying...

[image]
([This Google Search](https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=%22let%20me%20preface%20this%20by%20saying%20I%20don%27t%20mean%22), and [a broader search](https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=%22let%20me%20preface%20this%20by%22&start=10) with lots more examples)

So in your example, you could say

> *The speaker included a conciliatory **preface** before the question.*
>
> or
>
> *The speaker **prefaced** the question with a plea to not take offense*

If you were the speaker, you could even say

> *Let me preface this by asking that you not get angry. Are you rich?*
>
> or
>
> *Let me preface this by saying that I hope I don't offend you, but are you rich?*

---

Edited to add:

As EdwinAshworth points out, while preface-as-a-verb might be as likely to refer to a casual or spoken statement as to a formal, written work, the *primary* meaning of the noun is still an introduction to a book. However, I do believe the noun is used this way, perhaps influenced by the idiomatic usage of the verb. Some examples from around the internet (all emphases mine):

> I have noticed in the past few years that many of my students tend to
>   blurt out, “Wait” as **a preface** to a question they have. ([Jeff
>   Ortman, blog post](http://behs208.blogspot.com/2015/04/wait.html))
>
> **A preface** to a question that announces its content softens the
>   harshness or abruptness of the question itself. ([Carol E. Westby,
>   *Ethnographic Interviewing: Asking the Right Questions to the Right People in the Right Ways*](http://exodomedia.net/puentesculturales.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/13-Ethnographic-Interview.pdf))
>
> How come people say "no offense" as **a preface** to something they know darn well is offensive? ([Discussion board posting](http://www.democraticunderground.com/discuss/duboard.php?az=view_all&address=105x2595412))
>
> "Bless her heart" > A phrase used as a polite way of pitying a person or as **a preface** to
>   an insult (supposedly to lessen the injury). ([Cindy Pierce, *AOL
>   News*, "Dallas Slang"](http://www.aol.com/article/2010/08/26/dallas-slang/19591746/))
>
> Everyone understands that ‘with all due respect’ is usually **the
>   preface to an insult** ([Comment on a blog](http://www.thepassivevoice.com/2014/08/lee-child-on-amazon/))

And used sort of adjectively

> I just want you to know that this blog post will be about verbal
>   tee-ups, **the preface-y** phrases—“I’d like to say,” “To be perfectly
>   honest,” “No offense, but,” “I hate to be the one to tell you this,
>   but”—that either drive you crazy or allow you to get away with
>   conversational murder. ([Katy Waldman, *Slate*, "No Offense, but
>   Verbal Tee-Ups Aren't Actually Polite"](http://www.slate.com/blogs/xx_factor/2014/01/23/verbal_tee_ups_are_a_form_of_hedging_that_communicates_more_spite_than_sympathy.html))

In finding these examples, I noticed that [*prelude*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/prelude) is also often used, particularly in the set-phrase "prelude to an insult" (this has even been the title of a book and a song). *Preface* still seems more common outside of that particular usage, and a little more neutral in terms of connotations (whereas *preamble* feels legal and stuffy due to its association with things like the US Constitution, and *prelude* feels elegant and possibly snooty due to its musical meaning, either of which might be desirable depending on usage).

In short, it doesn't appear that there's a single agreed-upon term, though several would be widely-understood. You could also call it something like a "[preemptive](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pre-emptive) [pacification](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pacification)" which would be fairly precise but isn't particularly familiar.

Comment: I think that the noun 'preface' has broadened in usage far less than the verb. Though 'Let me preface this by saying that ...' is certainly idiomatic, calling the first part of a sentence a 'preface' seems a strained usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I definitely agree that the verb has loosened its connection to formal literary introductions far more than the noun has; however, I do think the noun is used this way, as noted in my edit.

Answer (score 37):

It's called a *preamble*.

> **Preamble** *noun*
>   1 A preliminary or preparatory statement; an introduction: *he could tell that what she said was by way of a preamble* [mass noun]: *I gave him the bad news without preamble*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/preamble)

Here are some examples taken from the internet:

- As a preamble to comments about the department's policy on distinction, please keep in mind that distinction in comps does not really matter much when it comes to your future plans. [- Chemistry Comps 2015-2016](https://apps.carleton.edu/curricular/chem/assets/2016_Comps_Document.pdf)
- Nancy Leigh's words would, no doubt, serve as a preamble to a major showdown between the two sisters ... [- Welcome to Higby by Mark Dunn](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=d54y0KO5NEoC&pg=PA125&dq=%22as%20a%20preamble%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ7aqtybnOAhVGpZQKHY55Bx0Q6AEITTAI#v=onepage&q=%22as%20a%20preamble%20to%22&f=false)

There's been some discussion on whether the leading part of the question's example sentence should be called a preamble or a preface. Both are valid. The term *preface* has a slightly stronger connotation of leading into the subject, while a *preamble* has a slightly stronger sense of simply being the portion before the main text. The portion in bold *prefaces* the question "Are you rich?", and serves as its *preamble*.

Comment: 'Preamble' may fit, but does not necessarily refer to a pragmatic-marker introductory clause that OP specifies. A preamble is usually an introductory paragraph etc spelling out what a document is about.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree.  I also think that 1006a's answer hits the nail on the head

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *Preamble* can refer to an introductory paragraph etc, as well as the *preface* to a sentence. Likewise, a *preface* can refer to a whole introductory chapter as well as the *preamble* of a sentence. The dictionary examples, especially the *mass noun* example, fit the OP's context. Nevertheless, I also like 1006a's *preface*. *Preface* can be used in the same sentence, whereas *preamble* is a label given only in the analysis of the sentence 'Let me *preface* this by saying X' is idiomatic for a speaker, versus 'He said X in the preamble' for a commenter on what the speaker said.

Comment: None of the examples labels an introductory part of a sentence _a preamble_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've edited my answer after considering the comments above.

Answer (score 2):

Such remarks might be described as *preliminary* as they're delivered before the main subject is broached.

If they come at the start of a conversation or change in subject then they might be described as *introductory*, as they set a frame for the information that follows.

They might even be described as *cursory* as they're often brief or hasty so as not to distract from or delay the main thought.

You might call this kind of phrase a *lead-in* as it's intended to guide (i.e. "lead") the listener toward or along a certain line of thought as the main subject is approached (i.e. as you're "getting into" the main subject).

Similarly, it may even be called a *warmup* if it's intended to make a sensitive subject or information less offensive. This alludes to "warming" the listener up to an otherwise "cold" or "chilling" topic.